# How do i $set and $push in one update MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to `$push` and `$set` at the same time, `$push` is working just fine, when it comes to `$set`, it generates this error:

> MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from
>   the query. Unexpanded update: files.$.name

Here's the code

```
Course.update(
    {
        _id: req.body.courseId,
        'files.fileUrl': { $ne: url }
    },{
        $push: { files: { fileUrl: url } },
        $set: {'files.$.name': file.name},
    }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log("Successfully saved")
    });
```

and the ORM model, I'm using mongoose

```
var CourseSchema = new Schema({
    files: [{
        fileUrl: String,
        name: { type: String, default: 'File name'}
    }]
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states looks like the query used is returning no documents or returning documents having no files[].

Another reason for which it might be throwing error is that you're trying to `$push` & `$set` in the same field `files` and probably running into an issue similar to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050

IMHO, there is no good reason to use the same field in `$push` & `$set`, instead you can simply change

```
$push: { files: { fileUrl: url } },
$set: {'files.$.name': file.name},
```

to

```
$push: { files: { fileUrl: url, name: file.name } },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written similar kind of query for my project 
Hope u could relative this to your scenario

```
exports.candidateRating = function(req, res) {
console.log(req.query);
console.log(req.body.RoundWiseRatings);
Profiles.update({
    "name": req.query.name
}, {
    $set: {
        "ratings": req.body.ratings,
    },
    $push: {
        "RoundWiseRatings": req.body.RoundWiseRatings
    }
}, {
    multi: true
}, function(error, profiles) {

    if (error) {

    }
    return Profiles.find({
        name: req.query.name
    }, function(err, profiless) {
        console.log(profiless);
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json(fnStruncturedData(profiless[0].RoundWiseRatings));
    });

});};
```

And this worked for me :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already added the multi: true, but still getting the same error. I believe my set is `$set: {'files.$.name': file.name}`,